# How can I reset the countdown in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following code which is going to countdown 3 seconds. but when is 0 I want to reset the seconds and when I call this function again to start counting.

```
var seconds = 3;
var second = 0;
var interval;

function countdown(){
    $("#counterOverlay").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $("#counter").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#counter").text((seconds - second));
        if (second >= seconds) {
            playVideo();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        second++;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: Simply reset the value of second like `second = 0`

Comment: @Satpal How can I get rid of 0 number I mean to show just 3 2 1

Answer (score 0):

Initialise `second` inside the function and change the function like this.

```
var seconds = 3;
var second;
var interval;

function countdown(){
    second = 0;
    $("#counterOverlay").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $("#counter").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    interval = setInterval(function() {

        if (second < seconds) {
            $("#counter").text((seconds - second));
            playVideo();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        second++;
    }, 1000);
}
```

It will reset second every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the value of `second` variable.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $("#counter").text((seconds - second));
    second++;
    if (second == seconds) {
        second = 0;
    }
}, 1000);
```

```js
var seconds = 3;
var second = 0;
var interval;


$("#counter").fadeTo(1000, 1);
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $("#counter").text((seconds - second));
  second++;
  if (second == seconds) {
    second = 0;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">a</div>
```

**Note:** I have intentionally removed following code snippet to keep things simple.

```
    if (second >= seconds) {
        playVideo();
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
```